# How to get path in project folder from unit test

Tags: c#

I have a unit test project and library project. I want to use the pdf file in library project as template. When I use Environment.CurrentDirectory I get path of the unit test project, but I want to get the path of the library project to reference pdf file.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "../PDFs/template.pdf");
```

What is the equivalent statement to get path to file in library project when executing the unit test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The unit test project has a copy of the referenced assembly in its `bin` folder and *that doesn't know about the original "source" location* (nor should it).

Unit tests should be able to execute in a vacuum, not relying on something to exist elsewhere in the filesystem (or ideally not rely on the filesystem or other external resources at all).

The only way to solve the problem as posited is to ensure that your "template.pdf" is copied to the output directory of the unit test, probably with a post-build step. A much better approach would be to just include the template in the unit test project.

Comment: After I add the template to test project as suggested, I used the following statement to get the path Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "../../PDFs/template.pdf"))

Comment: @billboard That sounds like it would work (again, probably should find another method at some point...) did you feel that I should include that in my answer?

Comment: Before I mark this as answer, I have a followup question so it is of no use to have the templates store in library. Because, no one using the library can access the files am i correct? In such a case, there is a potential the client using a wrong template and the library will throw exception

Comment: @billboard That is largely correct, you would need to distribute the template *with* your library and tell clients to use it. Extra files like this don't come along for the ride when a project adds a reference.

Comment: Can't you use [CallerFilePath]?

Comment: @BenLongo I doubt it. That has to be applied to an argument, presumably in the test. The source code isn't calling the test, the runner is, so it wouldn't have any extra information about the code that *it* is calling.

Comment: I’ve confirmed that it does work. If you place a function in the same assembly and call it with caller file path attribute it gives the source directory and you don’t have to copy and files into the bin directory.

Comment: @BenLongo Seems like a good answer to post on your own. To be clear, I'm not saying the attribute doesn't work, I'm saying that, off the top of my head, I don't think there's anywhere to put it in a test that would make it do what the OP wanted. Even if you could, it's not a good practice for a test assembly to be accessing the original source.

Comment: It doesn't seem like bad practice to me for tests - definitely for normal code. What problems would that cause?

Comment: @BenLongo It removes isolation from the test, ideally everything about the input is local to the test so its easily repeatable and maintainable. Under this scheme changing an unrelated file would potentially break the test.

Comment: It still seems local to the test to me but perhaps I'm misunderstanding. The alternative seems to be copying the files to the build directory. I don't see how there's any difference in repeatability or maintainability with that approach.

Comment: @BenLongo The test should use its own PDF I would think? Or even better, not actually read from the filesystem at all.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to not read from the filesystem if you are testing against PDFs that aren't generated from your code. Assuming the PDFs have to be on the filesystem _somewhere_, it seems quite reasonable to put them into the test project directory. I really don't see the problem with this.

Comment: @BenLongo The test project directory is fine. Unless I missed the OP's intent quite badly he wants it from the *actual* project's directory.

Comment: Ah now I see. I agree there doesn't seem to be a good reason to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the source directory of a project using `[CallerFilePath]`.

I usually do something like this:

```cs
internal static class ProjectSource {
    private static string CallerFilePath( [ CallerFilePath ] string? callerFilePath = null ) =>
        callerFilePath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(callerFilePath) );

    public static string ProjectDirectory() => Path.GetDirectoryName( CallerFilePath() )!;
}
```

Then from your tests you can do `ProjectSource.ProjectDirectory()` to obtain the project root. This should be used with care however. I mostly use this to read test data files to avoid copying them to bin.

Note that this can be used across projects as well if you make the change from `internal` to `public` but that could be considered bad practice.